# how to set good relative urls?

Tags: css, node.js, apache, url

Here's my architecture :

- i got a node server (Express) that provides REST services and also one EJS template
- on my production server, an Apache server redirects all requests on a certain port to my node server
- i got a front website. The entry point is the EJS provided by my node server. It also calls the REST services.

On my local computer, i can test my site on localhost:3000.
But on production, the url is like www.mysite.com/prod

With this configuration, it fails when i call www.mysite.com/prod because it can't find stylesheets and javascripts. Indeed these ones are searched at e.g. www.mysite.com/stylesheet.css instead of www.mysite.com/prod/stylesheet.css.

To solve that, I added a line in my Apache server configuration :

```
RewriteRule ^/prod$ /prod/ [R,L]
```

But I think there's a better way to do that, as I don't want users to be obliged to go to www.mysite.com/prod/ . The final '/' has just nothing to do there !

Any solution to do that ?

(If it's not clear, feel free to ask me more details)

Comment: If /prod is an actual sub-folder that the whole site runs in - then it rather should be called with a trailing slash. That is how folders _work_ - why mess with that?

Comment: Actually this site will be called through a kind of surrounding system named hypothes.is (that allows annotating the content of the site). Url will become https://via.hypothes.is/http://www.example.com/prod. Because of that (and i don't know why), calls to the REST API don't work anymore. By checking why, I noticed that it tried to call www.example.com/prod//myrestapi with a double slash '//'